# React testing library - external web component callback function is not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

i am currently using a external web component library on my react application. The library has custom button and other components.

The Button component has its own custom callback function, which i am using in my code.

While writing my test case when i use `fireEvent.click()`, the callback does not work.

can anyone tell me how to get the callback to work.

```
<ExButton exButtonClick={myFunc}> Button <ExButton>
```

Comment: What external component library are you using? Could you also provide your test case code?